# Windows service file listener only listens when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

First the code:

```
public partial class Watcher : ServiceBase
{
    private const string PathToFolder = @"D:\print\";

    public Watcher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    private void fileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Name != "test.txt")
        {
            return;
        }
        using (var r = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            var json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic tempTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            const string filename = PathToFolder + "textParsed.txt";
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }
            using (var file = File.CreateText(filename))
            {
                file.WriteLine(tempTest.Name.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there are changes to the `text.txt` file I'm suppose to parse the content of that text file and create another file. If I attach VS to the service and debug the service, the event gets fired, but when running normally, nothing happens.

The installer has LocalSystem privileges and that's pretty much all the changes I've made... Should be pretty straight forward, but somehow isn't.

Comment: Is it when you are running it manually or when you installs it as a service you're experience the problem?

Comment: The service is installed and set to automatic start

Comment: Have you tried seting service to run from your account? Seems like user rights problem

Comment: I've only tried LocalSystem and LocalService. I'll try User and let you know

Comment: I get a `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`